# Heroku deployment error : ImproperlyConfigured Django_Secret_key environment variable

Tags: django, heroku

I am deploying my django project to Heroku.
But secret key issue keeps popping up!

What could have been wrong? Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you!

```
State changed from crashed to starting 
Nov 20 16:37:53 heroku_app heroku/web.1:  Starting process with command `gunicorn config.wsgi:application --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='config.settings.production'`  
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app heroku/web.1:  State changed from starting to up 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:  [2016-11-20 05:37:55 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.5.0 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:  [2016-11-20 05:37:55 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:46247 (4) 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:  [2016-11-20 05:37:55 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:  [2016-11-20 05:37:55 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:  [2016-11-20 05:37:55 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:  [2016-11-20 05:37:56 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:  Traceback (most recent call last): 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 517, in spawn_worker 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      worker.init_process() 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      self.load_wsgi() 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 132, in load_wsgi 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi() 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      self.callable = self.load() 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      return self.load_wsgiapp() 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      return util.import_app(self.app_uri) 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      __import__(module) 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/config/wsgi.py", line 31, in <module> 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      application = get_wsgi_application() 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      django.setup() 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING) 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__ 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      self._setup(name) 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module) 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__ 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE) 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      __import__(name) 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/config/settings/production.py", line 24, in <module> 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      SECRET_KEY = env('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY') 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 111, in __call__ 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      return self.get_value(var, cast=cast, default=default, parse_default=parse_default) 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 253, in get_value 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg) 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:  ImproperlyConfigured: Set the DJANGO_SECRET_KEY environment variable 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:  [2016-11-20 05:37:56 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:  Traceback (most recent call last): 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 517, in spawn_worker 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      worker.init_process() 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      self.load_wsgi() 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 132, in load_wsgi 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi() 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      self.callable = self.load() 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      return self.load_wsgiapp() 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      return util.import_app(self.app_uri) 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      __import__(module) 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/config/wsgi.py", line 31, in <module> 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      application = get_wsgi_application() 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      django.setup() 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING) 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__ 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      self._setup(name) 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module) 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__ 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE) 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      __import__(name) 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/config/settings/production.py", line 24, in <module> 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      SECRET_KEY = env('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY') 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 111, in __call__ 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      return self.get_value(var, cast=cast, default=default, parse_default=parse_default) 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 253, in get_value 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:      raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg) 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:  ImproperlyConfigured: Set the DJANGO_SECRET_KEY environment variable 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:  [2016-11-20 05:37:56 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11) 
Nov 20 16:37:56 heroku_app app/web.1:  [2016-11-20 05:37:56 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
```

This is my wsgi.py file:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.production")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And this is my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn config.wsgi:application --log-file -
```

This first few lines of my production.py as extended setting file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from boto.s3.connection import OrdinaryCallingFormat
from django.utils import six


from .common import *  # noqa

# SECRET CONFIGURATION

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# django-secure
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSTALLED_APPS += ('djangosecure', )

SECURITY_MIDDLEWARE = (
    'djangosecure.middleware.SecurityMiddleware',
)
# Use Whitenoise to serve static files
# See: https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/
WHITENOISE_MIDDLEWARE = (
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer by myself again.

Problem turned out to be Django_Secret_Key missing from "Config Var" in Heroku//settings/.

Solution was: 
- `echo .env >> .gitignore`
- Edit all the security info it might need in your local .env file
- make sure there is no config var on the Heroku that has blank value, otherwise the next step can't over-write the current blank.
- in Heroku CLI: `heroku config:push`

Attempted solution: 
Use Heroku API. But only way use it manually is through CURL command. What a pain. Maybe I could design some interface to automate the CURL command typing process or send out RESTful configure commands.

Comment: You could use ansible or another tool to automate configuration